# Emacs - elisp code autocompletion in emacs-lisp-mode

Tags: company-mode, completion, auto-complete-mode

With below setup, my ielm mode has autocompletion function:

[image]

```
(require 'ac-slime)
(add-hook 'slime-mode-hook 'set-up-slime-ac)
(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'set-up-slime-ac)
(eval-after-load "auto-complete"
   '(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'slime-repl-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode))

(defun ielm-auto-complete ()                               
  "Enables `auto-complete' support in \\[ielm]."           
  (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-functions                   
                     ac-source-variables                   
                     ac-source-features                    
                     ac-source-symbols                     
                     ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
  (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'inferior-emacs-lisp-mode)        
  (auto-complete-mode 1))                                  
(add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook 'ielm-auto-complete)

(add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'ielm-mode-hook (lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends) '(company-elisp))))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook #'enable-paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook (lambda () (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends) '(company-elisp))))
```

But it doesn't work when edit a .el file. I guess I can not share the same function call ielm-auto-complete but don't know how to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below line should work:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'ielm-auto-complete)
```